# Unable to resolve module 'module://expo-font.js'

Tags: react-redux, react-native, expo, redux-thunk

i'm running react-native app via snacks.expo on the browser. Recently i'm getting the error. all are seems to be originating from the file where i use to fetch the api.

```
  Evaluating module://expo-font.js
  Evaluating module://react-native-elements.js
  Evaluating module://containers/fetchAPI.js
  Evaluating module://MainApplication.js
  Evaluating module://App.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

can you suggest what could be the reason. could it be something in my code.

Comment: Are you loading your fonts as described [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font)? and which version of expo are you using? it would be helpful if you list your installed packages in your package.json file.

Answer (score 2):

In the Snack interface, I updated package.json and it works.  The key is to add "expo-font":"^1.0.0".  Behind the scenes it resolves to expo-font@1.1.0.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta7",
    "expo-font": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~1.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~1.1.0"
 }
```

Comment: manually adding `"expo-font":"^1.0.0"` dosent resolves the problem, facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Expo from 'expo';
...
constructor(props) {
 super(props); 
 this.state = {
  isReady: false,
 }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
)
   render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <Expo.AppLoading />;
    }
    return (//Your component);
```